# How to change color textview based on Json result

Tags: android, json, textview

I just wanna make a change color textview based on Json result, example if the result of "statusspp" is SPP, color textview is RED and when the result of "statusspp" is SP2D, then the color textview is GREEN.

Here is my code :

```
package com.example.rizki.sp2dsearch;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.rizki.sp2dsearch.R.id.text;
import static com.example.rizki.sp2dsearch.R.id.textLat;

public class Search extends ListActivity {
    EditText editSearch;
    private static final String TAG_TOILETS = "toilets";
    private static final String TAG_NPWP = "npwp";
    private static final String TAG_NOSPP = "nospp";
    //private static final String TAG_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String TAG_STATUSSPP = "statusspp";
    private static final String TAG_TGLSP2D = "tglsp2d";
    private static final String TAG_JUMLAH = "jumlahtotal";
    //web service milik saya, silakan pakai untuk latihan
//url untuk melakukan get, parameter name saya kosongkan untuk nantinya diisi dengan keywords tertentu
    private static String url= "http://ditkeu.unair.ac.id/andro/carisp2d.php?npwp=";
    //urlget digunakan untuk url full yang dipanggil , url+keywords
    private static String urlget= "";
    static boolean a=false;
    JSONArray toilets = null;
    //deklarasi progressdialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> toiletList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    }
    public void searchtoi(View view)
    {
        editSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        //Mengambil keywords, dijadikan string
        String src = editSearch.getText().toString();
        urlget=url+src;
        //Log.e("a",urlget);
        new JSONParse().execute();

    }
    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        @Override
        //Menampilkan progress dialog
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Search.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Tunggu ya ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args)
        {
            //Membuat JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            //mengambil JSON String dari urlget, url+keywords
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(urlget);
            if(json==null)
            {
                a=false;
            }
            else a=true;
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            if(a==true)
            {
                try{
                    Log.e("status",a+"");
                    //mengambil array toilets
                    toilets = json.getJSONArray(TAG_TOILETS);
                    //loop pada toilets
                    for(int i=0; i<toilets.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject a = toilets.getJSONObject(i);
                        //simpan di variable
                        String nospp = a.getString(TAG_NOSPP);
                        String npwp = a.getString(TAG_NPWP);
                        //String type = a.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                        String statusspp = a.getString(TAG_STATUSSPP);
                        String tglsp2d = a.getString(TAG_TGLSP2D);
                        String jumlahtotal = a.getString(TAG_JUMLAH);
                        Log.e("npwp",npwp);

                        //buat hashmap baru untuk store String
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(TAG_NOSPP, nospp);
                        map.put(TAG_NPWP, npwp);
                        map.put(TAG_STATUSSPP, statusspp);
                        map.put(TAG_TGLSP2D, tglsp2d);
                        map.put(TAG_JUMLAH, jumlahtotal);
                        toiletList.add(map);
                        //ProgressDialog dihilangkan jika sudah selesai mengambil data
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        tampilkandata();
                    }
                }catch(JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error getting data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("status",a+"");}
        }
    }
    public void tampilkandata()
    {

        //membuat ListView dari data JSON yang ada
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, toiletList,
                R.layout.list_view,
                new String[]{TAG_NPWP, TAG_STATUSSPP, TAG_TGLSP2D, TAG_JUMLAH}, new int[]{
                R.id.name,R.id.latitude, R.id.longitude,R.id.price});
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv=getListView();

        // Memberikan Event Click Listener pada List View
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                //Mengambil nilai dari ListView yang di Click
                String npwp = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String statusspp = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.latitude)).getText().toString();
                String tglsp2d = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.longitude)).getText().toString();
                String jumlahtotal = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price)).getText().toString();

                //Membuat intent untuk menampilkan activity Detail
                //Selain itu Intent ini juga digunakan untuk mengirimkan suatu data
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Detail.class);
                //Memasukkan data yang akan dikirimkan melalui intent
                i.putExtra(TAG_NPWP, npwp);
                i.putExtra(TAG_STATUSSPP, statusspp);
                i.putExtra(TAG_TGLSP2D, tglsp2d);
                i.putExtra(TAG_JUMLAH, jumlahtotal);
                startActivity(i);
                //Menampilkan data dari ListView yang di Click dalam bentuk popup
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "toilet "+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

once you have your data ready
you can simply use switch cases

```html
switch(case){
  case SPP:
    textview.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getColor(R.color.RED))
case SP2D:
 textview.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getColor(R.color.GREEN))
}
```

make sure you define your colors in the colors xml first

Comment: wherever you wish to set the color.provided u have the values for case,in your code it is not entirely clear which textview and where u wanna perform this action.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your textView before listView onItemClickListener and use setTextColor method to change the textColor

example

```
TextView text =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.latitude));
String statusspp = text.getText().toString();

if(statusspp.equals("SPP")){
   text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
   text. setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);//to change background}
else if(statusspp.equals("SP2D")){
   text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
   text. setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);//to change background}
```

Note: Dont initialize like this `String statusspp = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.latitude)).getText().toString();` you wont be able to reuse the code

Comment: its work sir..but the background color change only when i have to click it.

Comment: Then initialize your textviews outside the item click listener and move the above code inside the item click listener

Comment: Sorry sir, i dont understand how to initialize textviews outside the item click listener. Can yo give me a little example sir?

Comment: i still have a problem with this..please help sir

Comment: what is the problem that you face

Comment: how do i Initialize textView before listView onItemClickListene

Comment: Can you please refer this tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)